# Make text fill only the remaining space in a table cell

Tags: html, css

Preconditions: I am limited to old browsers (around Chrome 25), which do not support a lot of CSS features. Also, the table structure with 3 columns needs to remain, and the first column should not take more space, than it needs.

Goal: I have an info element, which specifies the overall width and a red box within the cell, which already takes up some space. Furthermore, I want the text element to fill the remaining space, without pushing the red box out of the boundaries. Note, that the parent width and the box width could be dynamic values, depending on the screen resolution. I tried to wrap the according cell in another flex box combined with "flex: 1 1 0" and many other things, and ChatGPT also had no answer.

Do you have a solution? Or is it not solvable with the requirements?

```css
.info {
  width: 600px; /* dynamic */
  background: lightgray;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row :first-child {
  border-right: solid black 20px;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 300px; /* dynamic */
  background: red;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; /* needs to fill the remaining space, without pushing the box out of its parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">1.1</div>
        <div class="cell ">1.2</div>
        <div class="cell ">1.3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">2.1</div>
        <div class="cell">
          <div class="flex">
            <div class="text">This is a text, too long to fit inside the container</div>
            <div class="box"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">2.3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each row can only consist of a single line, thus white-space: nowrap is required. That part of the text, that needs to be cut of, should be hidden with overlap: hidden.

Current Layout:
[image]

Expected Layout:
[image]

Comment: Why Chrome 25? That's from 2013, over 10 years ago. Flex was barely even a thing back then and you needed a prefix to use it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I would also prefer to use all modern features. Unfortunately, the hardware from the customer is old, and the browser is not going to be updated, thus I have to find a solution for Chromium 25

Comment: You can't get an ellipsis or overflow hidden without setting a limitation on `width`. So I suspect this is not solvable given your specific constraints (*sans* Javascript).

Comment: Yes. I used JS to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table, use `<table>`.
Although it is quite dirty, you can wrap the text in `<div>` and add `position: absolute;`
Example:

```css
.info {
  max-width: 600px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table td {
  width: 0;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">
            This is a very long text This is a very long text This is a very long text
          </div>
          <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I switched between a html table and a css table (displa: table) but at some point I lost the overview what I already tried. This is definitely a workaround I will try out! thank you :)